# I have linear expression and I want its value per different value for variables in python

Tags: python-2.7, mathematical-optimization

I am working on a specific optimization problem.
In a part of my code, I need to have the value of a linear expression per different set of value for variables.
for example my linear expression is something like 15 + 4*X1 + 6*X2 + 5*X3 and 
I want to have different value of this linear expression per different value of (X1,X2,X3)
I can do it my self by writing code but I want to know if there is a specific method to simply give the value of variables and linear expression and it returns the value.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> f = lambda X1, X2, X3: 15 + 4*X1 + 6*X2 + 5*X3
>>> f(1, 2, 3)
46
```